# obtain an Image with Jquery and Php

Tags: php, jquery, image

I want to obtain images from the server.

The html code :

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

Here is my code in jquery :

```
$.post('php/Image.php', function(data) {
        $('#container').html(data);
    });
```

And the php code :

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$img = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
imagepng($img);
```

On my web page I can see the "binary" of the image and that's not what I expect. Somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Or if there is a better solution to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `Image.php` returns an image, not a `<img />` tag., you should do `<img src='php/Image.php'>` instead at least for what you're showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to request the image body itself, but insert an `img` tag with link to it:

```
$('#container').html('<img src="php/Image.php" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your PHP isn't stripped down (only reads an image and sends it), you can simply request the image from the server by changing the `src` attribute of your `img` tag, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/JntrA/).

All you need to add now is an `<img>` tag to your HTML:

```
$('#container').html('<img src="php/Image.php">');
```